# Cycles (Experimental) doesn't work with custom geometry attributes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, geometry-nodes

Just trying to confirm / clarify the issue with blender 3.0 version.
I'm preserving original geometry point positions (custom vecor attribute) on a geometry to get a consistent procedural pattern material shading when the geo is getting deformed. The attribute is created with the Geometry Nodes modifier from 'Positon' plugged in to a custom named output then material reads this attribute through the 'Attribute' node. This technique works fine with the Cycles [Supported] but once I switch to Cycles [Experimental] the attribute read in the material network stops working (with custom attributes) - it is still working with the standard internal attributes like 'generated' or 'uv'. Is this a known limitation of the Experimental mode or there are workarounds/options to get this issue sorted?

[EDIT]

Thanks for the answers. I've spent some more time debugging the problem and I guess I found what's not working:

- Cycles Experimental Adaptive Subdivision doesn't see custom attributes generated by GeometryNodes
- (Also) GeometryNodes modifier is 'blocking' adaptive subdivision feature when placed after subdivision modifier in the modifiers stack

Examples:

This is the subd shading reusing the original Geometry position:

[image]

.. and this is switching to the custom attributes generated by Geometry Nodes

[image]

.. and also this is rearranging modifiers stack so that GeometryNodes is resolved after the subdivision resulting in adaptive option gone from the subdivision - as the result myPos custom attribute is getting into the material (as a cost of dorpping adaptive subdivision)

[image]

Comment: maybe show us a screenshot of your node setup?

Comment: I don't have such problems, clarify your setup. Screenshots of nodes of shader and GN should be helpful.